# R - cut a specific column from multiple files and bind them altogether

Tags: r, subset

I have multiple files (30, tab delimited) that look like the one below:

`|target_id    | length| eff_length| est_counts|      tpm|
|:------------|------:|----------:|----------:|--------:|
|LmjF.27.1250 |    966|    823.427|       2932|  94.7314|
|LmjF.09.0430 |   1410|   1267.430|       3603|  75.6304|
|LmjF.13.0210 |   2001|   1858.430|       4435|  63.4897|
|LmjF.28.0530 |   4083|   3940.430|       7032|  47.4778|
|LmjF.16.1400 |    591|    448.577|       1163|  68.9761|
|LmjF.29.2570 |   1506|   1363.430|      11135| 217.2770|`

I am trying to cut the fifth column from all of these files 30 files with a command such as:

`fifth_colum_file1 = file1.csv[ , 5]`

But I want to make the process more automatised.

The files that I want to work with have all the pattern "bs_abundance", therefore I think a good starting point would be to either load all the files I want to work with with such a command:

`temp = list.files(pattern="*bs_abundance")`

Or perhaps I can also load all the tables I want to work with directly into the working space already:

`for(i in temp) {
  x <- read.table(i, header=TRUE, comment.char = "A", sep="\t")
  assign(i,x)

}`

Then, as explained, I want to cut the fifth column of each of the files to later bind them all to another table of same number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method using `lapply` that assumes each file in the folder has the same number of rows.

```
# get file names
files <- dir("temp")
# remove one file
files <- files[-which(files == "removeFileName")]
# get list of vectors from 29 files
myList <- lapply(files, function(i) {temp <- read.csv(i); temp[, 5]})
# get new data.frame
dfDone <- do.call(data.frame, myList)
```

Comment: I got all the file names with `files <- list.files(pattern="*bs_abundance")` because I do not want to load all the files that are in a folder. Rather, I want to load them based on a pattern (bs_abundance). I now have a `files`with the 29 files from which I want to extract the fifth column. How the rest of the code would look like then?

Comment: The third and fourth lines (`myList <- ...` and `dfDone <- `) should do the trick at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me just clarify two things. Do I have to put the path to the folder where my files are on line 2, like `files <- dir("/path/to/my/files/")`? And if I do so, what shall I put on the sixth line where `temp` is written?

Comment: In your previous comment you mention that you are using `list.files(pattern...)` to get the file names. Use that code. For the second question, it should run properly without change. `temp` in the `lapply` line is a dummy object that temporarily stores the current csv file.

Comment: Also tried to get the file names with `list.files(pattern)` and the result was the same. The error also persist: I get the error `Error: unexpected 'function' in "myList <- lapply(files function"` after I run the command `myList <- lapply(files function(i) {temp <- read.table(i); temp[, 5]})`

Comment: Aha. i caught a typo in my code `lapply(files function` needed a comma. I've added it in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Put the files into a folder. For this example let's call it `temp`. Set your working directory appropriately or specify the full path for the example below.

```
cols  <- as.character()
files <- dir("temp")
for(i in files){
 # You didn't mention a file type, but let's say it's csv
 tmp  <- read.csv(files[i], header = T)
 tmp  <- tmp[, 5]
 cols <- cbind(cols, tmp) 
}
```

Then you can just `cbind` the columns in `cols` with your final data object.

Comment: The files are text files, tab delimited. I put all the files I wanted to open in a folder and put the path on the second line `files <- dir("/path/to/my/files")`.
I think the first two lines of the script are working (after I hit the second line, all the files that I wanted to open were on the vector `files`. But when I tried to execute the script from the third line on, got the message:
`Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'NA': No such file or directory`.

Comment: and before that I have set the working directory to the folder where all the files are.